# PhpStorm and Xdebug configuration

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have problem to run my tests with Xdebug. Xdebug doesn't stop to the breakpoint, it says after I try in PHPStorm, in the below corner on the left " Connection was not established Cannot start debugger session with 'Xdebug 2.8.1'

Some info about my environment:

- PHP 7.4.20 (I installed this version from homebrew)
- Xdebug 2.8.1

In my phpinfo:

```
Runtime:       PHP 7.4.20 with Xdebug 2.8.1
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/xdebug.ini

PHP API => 20190902
PHP Extension => 20190902
Zend Extension => 320190902
Zend Extension Build => API320190902,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20190902,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => enabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => available, disabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2, tlsv1.3
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.20, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.8.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
```

This is the xdebug session that I found in phpinfo

```
xdebug

xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.8.1
IDE Key => bpalumbo
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support

Supported protocols
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => /var/tmp/ => /var/tmp/
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /var/tmp/ => /var/tmp/
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => On => On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.20/bin/xdebug.log => /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.20/bin/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_log_level => 7 => 7
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.remote_timeout => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /var/tmp/ => /var/tmp/
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

Here the xdebug log

```
[5468] Log opened at 2021-06-11 14:26:14
[5468] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[5468] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[5468] I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[5468] W: Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000. :-|
[5468] I: Connected to client. :-)
[5468] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///Users/bpalumbo/workspace/commercetools-php-sdk/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.0" protocol_version="1.0" appid="5468" idekey="18793"><engine version="2.8.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2019 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[5468] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[5468] Log closed at 2021-06-11 14:26:15
```

If I run here `/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.20/bin` the phpize says (I don't know if it's connected):

```
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
```

In my `php.ini` I didn't add anything about Xdebug configuration, but I have the `xdebug.ini` where I can find:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `I guess it's connected to the thing that says Debug Build => no` is unrelated. It is only about whether PHP is compiled into "debug" mode, which is something PHP's creators use.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking here. Xdebug is loaded, as it shows up in the phpinfo() output. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Derick Xdebug doesn't stop to the breakpoint, it says after I try in PHPStorm, in the below corner on the left " Connection was not established Cannot start debugger session with 'Xdebug 2.8.1'

Comment: @Edea_Barby This is a very broad "does not work" statement with no details. 1) Show your live Xdebug settings (whole Xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output) 2) Enable Xdebug log and try to debug -- then see what it has there (if it tries to connect (if at all) and what the response is). 3) Better upgrade to Xdebug 3 -- it's a bit easier to troubleshoot there. 4) Check the links below.

Comment: @Edea_Barby Anyway: 1) https://learnxdebug.com/ 2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw 3) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ 4) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html

Comment: thanks @LazyOne I updated the initial text with your requests I cannot update Xdebug because I read that with my php version  Xdebug3 is not compatible

Comment: @Edea_Barby Change Xdebug port  from default `9000` to another one (e.g. `9003` -- used by default in Xdebug 3). Do this in both PHP (xdebug.ini I guess) and PhpStorm. The TCP 9000 port seems to be already in use by **php-fpm** (also uses that port by default + the typical response that you can see in such case) or some another service that is aware of the Xdebug protocol. Homebrew means Mac, right? If so -- PhpStorm has issues with detecting already used ports on Mac. But you can check what uses that port with `netstat` or alike program (e.g. `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN`)

Comment: @Edea_Barby *"I cannot update Xdebug because I read that with my php version Xdebug3 is not compatible"* That's is not true. Xdebug 3.0.x supports PHP 7.2 and newer so it definitely works with your PHP 7.4 (I'm using it with 7.2, 7.3, 7.4 & 8.0 on my Windows 10).

Comment: @LazyOne FYI this is what I found https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1981 
about the problem between Xdebug 3 and php 7.4, so I have problem to update it. But I tried with your suggestion changing the xdebug port and it works!  Great :) Thanks a lot to both of you for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Xdebug log you need to change Xdebug port from default `9000` to some another number (e.g. `9003` -- used by default in Xdebug 3). Do this in both PHP (xdebug.ini in your case I guess) and PhpStorm.

On your computer TCP 9000 port seems to be already in use by **php-fpm** (it also uses that port by default + the typical response that you can see in such case) or some another service that is aware of the Xdebug protocol.

Homebrew means Mac, right? PhpStorm has issues with detecting already-in-use ports on Mac (hence no warning from the IDE: on Windows and Linux you would see a warning in such situation). You can check what process uses that port with `netstat` or alike program (e.g. `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` on Mac).